# Transfer Data from Sheet to Sheet and fix `424` Object required

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to transfer Data from a sheet to another if some conditions are met (Same Column Data).

I think I have found a way to do it but I am unable to select the row number of my tables (they are not fixed)

```
   Sheet 1      

Buyer   Item    Quantity    
Jack    Pen     16  
Jack    Table   3   
Jack    Chair   9   
Mark    Pen     10  
Mark    Chair   2   
Alice   Chair   4   


   Sheet 2      

Buyer Pen Table Chair
Jack  16    3     9
Mark  10          2
Alice             4
```

You see I want the quantities in Sheet 1 to go in the right columns in Sheet 2

Edited error: error on the first if:
`424` Object required

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet

    Set sh1 = Me.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    Set sh2 = Me.Worksheets("Sheet 2")

    For i = 2 To sh2.Range(sh2.Cells("1", "A"), sh2.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

        For j = 2 To sh1.Range(sh1.Cells("1", "A"), sh1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

            If sh1.Cells(j, "A").Value Is sh2.Cells(i, "A").Value Then

                For r = 3 To 16

                    If sh1.Cells(j, 16).Value Is sh2.Cells(1, r).Value Then

                        sh2.Cells(j, r).Value = sh1.Cells(i, 18).Value

                    End If

                 Next

            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry if this has already been posted.

Comment: Qualify everything... `sh1.Range(sh1.Cells("1", "A"), sh1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`.  If you don't tell it what sheet, it will take the active sheet, same as the line beforehand, which uses `sh2`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can do this easily with a Pivot Table, or SUMIFS functions. May I ask why you need it in VBA?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thank you! I need the second table in "sheet 2" in this format because it is a template that has to be entered in a bigger system.
I Chose VBA because I learned some in school and I have no clue how to do it in another way. If you have suggestions I'd be glad to take them.

Comment: @Cyril, Thank you it's true I forgot to define this part, I have a new error that I will put in my edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:
Assuming that you have 2 sheets named 'Sheet1' and 'Sheet2'

```
Sub match_data()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim buyer As String
Dim item As String
Dim quantity As Integer
For a = 2 To sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    buyer = sh1.Range("A" & a).Value
    item = sh1.Range("B" & a).Value
    quantity = sh1.Range("C" & a).Value

    'Look if buyer already exist in Sheet2
    Dim buyer_exist As Boolean: buyer_exist = False

    If sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then
        For b = 2 To sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If sh2.Range("A" & b).Value = buyer Then
                buyer_exist = True
                'look for the right column to place the number
                For c = 2 To 4
                    If sh2.Cells(1, c).Value = item Then
                        'assign the quantity
                        sh2.Cells(b, c).Value = quantity
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next c
            End If
        Next b

        'Add a new row for the buyer
        If buyer_exist = False Then
            For c = 2 To 4
                If sh2.Cells(1, c).Value = item Then
                    'assign the quantity
                    sh2.Cells(sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Value = buyer
                    sh2.Cells(sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, c).Value = quantity
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c
        End If

    Else
        'Add a new row for the buyer
        If buyer_exist = False Then
            For c = 2 To 4
                If sh2.Cells(1, c).Value = item Then
                    'assign the quantity
                    sh2.Cells(sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Value = buyer
                    sh2.Cells(sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, c).Value = quantity
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c
        End If

    End If

Next a


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, this code looks very good, I am reviewing it and I think I understand everything and can apply it to my tables. However I don't know if the last part of your code is here twice on purpose

Comment: I have adapted your code and removed the duplicate and it works fine thank you!
I just need a way to add the numbers if there are several lines with the same item in the first sheet.

Comment: Yes, it's the same code but that is not duplicate. I just avoided to add a function to not make the code complicated. I suggest not to delete that part of the code.

Comment: to add the numbers/quantity just replace all the line similar on this code "sh2.Cells(b, c).Value = quantity" to "sh2.Cells(b, c).Value = sh2.Cells(b, c).value + quantity"

Comment: I think the best solution for that is to clear the Sheet2 Range first every time you launch the program. Go to sheet2 and select "A1:D10000" for example then name that range to "ouput" for example only. THen on your code after setting the sh2 variable add a line like this -  sh2.range("output").clear